# What Block / Controller creates an order in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, orders, event-observer

What block creates an order in Magento2? Basically I need a plugin or observer to make an api call right after the order is created.

Answer (score 1):

I have made one extension and used below events with order event.

```
app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Onepage/SaveOrder.php
checkout_controller_onepage_saveOrder

app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Onepage/Success.php
checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
```

Let me know you are searching for the same or anything else. Good Luck!!